# ServiceStack: httpReq.GetRawBody() is empty

Tags: servicestack

I have a global requestfilter from where i want to log all http traffic using log4net - company restriction. Problem is that the InputStream is always lenght = 0. The soap envelope is desezerialized correctly and execution of service is succesfull, but inputstream is unavailable after first serialization. Is this wrong approach, if i want to log all ingoing and outgoing http traffic? What should i do to accomplish this? I do not want to log the deserialized requestDto.

```
this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
{
    LogManager.LogFactory.GetLogger(this.GetType()).Info(httpReq.GetRawBody());
});
```

Error seems to occur in type ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Support.SoapHandler in method, where using statement closes stream without buffering it:

```
 protected static Message GetRequestMessage(Stream inputStream, MessageVersion msgVersion)
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(inputStream))
        {
            var requestXml = sr.ReadToEnd();

            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(requestXml);

            var msg = Message.CreateMessage(new XmlNodeReader(doc), int.MaxValue,
                msgVersion);

            return msg;
        }
    }
```

When i try to access GetRawBody on type ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions the following logic is executed:

```
 public string GetRawBody()
    {
        if (bufferedStream != null)
        {
            return bufferedStream.ToArray().FromUtf8Bytes();
        }

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(InputStream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Here I would expect the inpustream to be buffered, since it Inputstreaem is no longer available (lenght = 0).

Isn't this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen  [Request Logger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) or [IRequiresRequestStream](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#reading-directly-from-the-request-stream). These might help provide some insight on logging requests. Also, I don't believe InputStream would have a length on GET requests.

Comment: I have seen it. When using soap it always uses post method. Funny thing is that it works for JSON but not Soap.

Comment: Would inheriting from IRequiresSoapMessage help? https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support#raw-access-to-wcf-soap-message